# Gridding Pandas DataFrame to Multi-Dimensional Xarray Dataset?

Tags: python, dataframe, python-xarray

Is there a way to grid a "row format" dataset into an xarray Dataset without using a loop?

Specifically, I would like an array where all values in the (lat, lon, time) grid are 0 if no value is specified. I am aware of the `.to_xarray()` method in pandas (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_xarray.html), but this will not generate full coverage of the desired coordinates (lat, lon, time). Toy example below:

```
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr 

# row data to be gridded
data = {'lats':[0,0,2], 'lons':[1,2,0], 'times':[0,1,2], 'values':[20,50,30]}
df_rows = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
# desired coordinates to grid onto:
lat = [0,1,2]
lon = [0,1,2]
time= [0,1,2]
```

```
# general form of the desired output Dataset
df_grid = xr.Dataset(data_vars={'data':(('lon','lat','time'), df_rows)},
                     coords={'lat': lat,
                             'lon': lon,
                             'time':time})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `xr.Dataset.from_dataframe` would do :

```
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

# row data to be gridded
data = {"lat": [0, 0, 2], "lon": [1, 2, 0], "time": [0, 1, 2], "values": [20, 50, 30]}
df_rows = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index(["time", "lon", "lat"])

ds = xr.Dataset.from_dataframe(df_rows)
```

`ds` is a `xarray.Dataset`, with three dimensions/coordinates, and one variable `values` which is a 3x3x2 block of data.

Setting `time`, `lon` and `lat` as index in `df_rows` is essential, as these columns will be understood as coordinates.

Note that this method will fill your variable `values` with `nan` for the coordinates tuples where `values` is not specified.